# Generating Sourcemaps from Browserify inside Node script

Tags: node.js, browserify, source-maps

Hi We've been provided with some code, however we need to try and get browserify to generate the site maps, however I cannot figure out how to do it, all the variations I can figure out from the documentation i've exhausted, so I'm clearly not doing something right, however cannot figure out what it is.

Would you guys be able to show how to generate a sourcemap via browserify from within a nodejs script.

```
var b              = require('browserify'),
    fs             = require('fs'),
    path           = require('path'),
    browserify     = b({ debug: true }),
    UglifyJS       = require('uglify-js'),
    lang           = process.argv[2] || 'en-gb',
    _input         = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/app.js'),
    _output        = path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundle.' + lang + '.js');

browserify.add(_input);
browserify.transform(require("jadeify"));

var bundler = browserify.bundle(),
    writer  = bundler.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(_output));

writer.on('finish', function(){

    console.log('finished!');

});
```